# Adding attributes based on the XML tag position

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the XML structure like below:

```
<root>
<section id="c001">
<cl:xref target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_1"/>
<cl:xref target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_2"/>
<cl:xref target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_3"/>
</section>
<section id="c002">
<cl:xref target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_2"/>
</section>
<section id="c003">
<cl:xref target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_1"/>
</section>
</root>
```

And I need convert the above XML into below format with attribute called `preference`.

```
<root>
<section id="c001">
<cl:xref target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_1" preference="1"/>
<cl:xref target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_2" preference="1"/>
<cl:xref target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_3" preference="1"/>
</section>
<section id="c002">
<cl:xref target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_2" preference="0"/>
</section>
<section id="c003">
<cl:xref target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_1" preference="0"/>
</section>
</root>
```

Can anybody help me how to add the attribute `preference="1"` for first occurrence and `preference="0"` for all other occurrences using XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

**Your XML is not well formed because it uses undeclared namespace prefixes.  First, fix that:**

```
<root xmlns:cl="http://xml.cengage-learning.com/cendoc-core">
  <section id="c001">
    <cl:xref target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_1"/>
    <cl:xref target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_2"/>
    <cl:xref target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_3"/>
  </section>
  <section id="c002">
    <cl:xref target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_2"/>
  </section>
  <section id="c003">
    <cl:xref target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_1"/>
  </section>
</root>
```

*Note: I've made an assumption regarding the namespace definition for the `cl:` prefix; you may need to adjust to be the actual namespace if I've guessed wrong.*

**Second, adapt the identity transform by adding a template for the common `cl:xref` case that does the usual copying plus adding `@preference = 1` and another template for the specific `cl:xref` case where its parent is the first `section`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:cl="http://xml.cengage-learning.com/cendoc-core">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cl:xref">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="preference">0</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cl:xref[../count(preceding::section) = 0]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="preference">1</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Running this transform against the corrected input XML document yields the desired output XML document:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:cl="http://xml.cengage-learning.com/cendoc-core">
  <section id="c001">
    <cl:xref preference="1" target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_1"/>
    <cl:xref preference="1" target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_2"/>
    <cl:xref preference="1" target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_3"/>
  </section>
  <section id="c002">
    <cl:xref preference="0" target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_2"/>
  </section>
  <section id="c003">
    <cl:xref preference="0" target-type="generated-number" link-target="ch12_fig_1"/>
  </section>
</root>
```